# build apaga arquivos

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Gostaria de saber se alguem ja passo por isso ? quando gero a build do app 
IONIC

```
ionic build android
```

ele apaga qualquer outro arquivo que esteja dentro do direitorio /js que não seja o app.js e o controllers.js

oque faço ?

Comment: Onde exatamente está `/js` ?  o diretório `platforms` não deve ser usado para armazenar seus fontes.